# WriteFile error 0x80004005 on Azure Websites

Tags: c#, winapi, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple website running on Azure Websites. It's using native code that basically writes into file when called. Everything works fine, most of the time. But sometimes (as far as I observe it's random - once a week to once a month) I got error `0x80004005`:

```
 (0x80004005): I/O error during "WriteFile" operation for file "C:\DWASFILES\SITES\***\VIRTUALDIRECTORY0\SITE\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\***"
Error while trying to write to file ---> I/O error during "WriteFile" operation for file "C:\DWASFILES\SITES\***\VIRTUALDIRECTORY0\SITE\WWWROOT\APP_DATA\***"
Error while trying to write to file
```

If I stop the application and start it again in a one or two seconds everything is back to normal.

The application is running in shared mode.

Any idea what's wrong? Or what to try to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: When this issue occurs is it persistent (or fails once then succeeds)?

Comment: It's persistent. Or at least last time it was persistent for 6 hours. Then I did the stop&start magic.